How to use if contains within an arrayformula and multiple or conditions?
I want to replace the "=" in the following example with a text contain to match entries partially instead of entirely.
However, I cannot get this to work. I thought I could replace the (A2:A="Neckarau / Lindenhof") with a regexmatch(A2:A;"Neckarau") but I am getting a formula parse error.
Can anyone help me with this?
={"Anzahl";arrayformula(IF((A2:A="Selbstabholer")+(A2:A="Neckarau / Lindenhof")+(A2:A="Seckenheim /  Edingen")+(A2:A="Wallstadt / Oikos / Spinelli")>0;"";IF((A2:A<>"")*(I2:I="")*(I3:I="")=1;"ausblenden";IF(I2:I="";"";H2:H))))}


I provided an answer below that includes the meat and potatoes but leaves out the  "Anzahl" as I'm not sure what your intention is. It would be helpful if you included an example of your expected result. Once you [edit] to clarify what it should be, I can update the formula.   You used a Row separator ; between it and the rest of the formula, but that would return 2 rows for every one checked.

Note to readers:
The OP @orschiro is in a locale that uses a comma , as the decimal separator. Refer to the table Separators by Locale at the bottom to avoid formula parsing errors if your locale uses a period/dot instead.

Formula
=INDEX(IFS(
   REGEXMATCH(A2:A; JOIN("|"; J1:J4));;
   LEN(A2:A)*(I2:I=""); "ausblenden";
   LEN(I2:I); H2:H; 1;)) 


The formula uses IFS instead of nested IF functions to make it shorter and easier to follow:IFS
----------------------------  
=IFS(condition1; if_true1;
     condition2; if_true2;
     condition3; if_true3) 
Nested IF
----------------------------
=IF(condition1; if_true1;
   IF(condition2; if_true2;
     IF(condition3; if_true3; if_false3)

The last IFS condition 1;, where the condition 1 is equivalent to TRUE and the value is empty, is a catchall.
In the REGEXMATCH, the regular expression is created by joining a word list from range J1:J4. If you prefer, it can be hardcoded in the formula. For example:
=INDEX(IFS(
   (A2:A="Selbstabholer")+(A2:A="Neckarau")+
     (A2:A="Seckenheim")+(A2:A="Wallstadt");;
   LEN(A2:A)*(I2:I=""); "ausblenden";
   LEN(I2:I); H2:H; 1;))



Additional Notes

You included Column I twice in your code with mismatched starting rows. I assume this was accidental:
IF((A2:A"")*(I2:I="")*(I3:I="")=1

When an IF function's if_true condition is a non-zero number and the if_false condition is zero, or vice versa, there is no need to test the result. For example:
Non-Zero # = TRUE
--------------------  
IF(1;  true; false)=TRUE
IF(0;  true; false)=FALSE                   
IF(3;  true; false)=TRUE
IF(-3; true; false)=TRUE 

Non-Zero # = FALSE
----------------------
IF(1;  false; true)=FALSE
IF(0;  false; true)=TRUE
IF(3;  false; true)=FALSE
IF(-3; false; true)=FALSE

In Google Sheets, if you want to return an empty value do not supply an empty text string "" as they are different and can cause problems in certain formulas. See this recent answer:
USE: IF(x;true;)   INSTEAD OF: IF(x;true;"")


Separators by Locale
The key locale differentiator is whether a period/dot or a comma is used as the decimal separator.




A
B
C
D
E




1 
Locales      
Decimal    
Argument          
Array Column       
Array Row             


2
NA, UK, AU
Period1=1.00
CommaIF(x, 1, 0)
Comma{A1, B1, C1}
Semicolon{A1; A2; A3}


3
EU
Comma1=1,00
SemicolonIF(x; 1; 0)
Backslash{A1\ B1\ C1}
Semicolon{A1; A2; A3}



